# JAVA Reading a text file and importing a text file

Tags: text, integer

[sdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3kI7.png)

I am doing this assignment and I got stuck at the very first. I can't even read the given text file. Help me guys. please check the attachment and see where I am wrong

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: popData.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
> at dd.main(dd.java:13)
> ```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try use standard Java classes

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
try {
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // process line
}
} finally {
br.close();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't even read the file. Can you look at the edited description and help me out. Thanks!

Comment: When you run the program, the "popData.txt" file needs to be in the same directory as the .class file generated by the compiler, not the .java file. In an IDE like Netbeans, put the file in the project folder, not the source folder